# Spacebars-generated dynamic links do not trigger Iron Router in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, iron-router, spacebars

I've got this in my routes:

```
Router.route('/videos/:id', {
  name: 'VideoPage',
  data: function(){
    return Videos.findOne(this.params.id);
  }
})
```

This template shows up at the route above:

```
Template.VideoPage.helpers({

 'videoIds': function(){

    var myVideoIds = [
        "23456",
        "h5e45t",
        "f4e4w",
        "g6h4h"
    ];

    return myVideoIds;

  }

});
```

HTML:

```
<template name="VideoPage">

{{videoTitle}}

<p>Click the links below to get to a new video page</p>

{{#each videoIds}}

    <a href="/videos/" + {{this}}>

{{/each}}

</template>
```

When I click on a link, the URL in the browser changes from something like `/videos/23456` to something like `/videos/f4e4w`, but the request never actually goes through Iron Router and the `Router.route` function. I put a `debugger` before Router.route and it triggers on initial page load but does NOT trigger when the links are clicked.

I understand that Iron Router's default behavior is NOT to re-render a template the user is currently on, but this is the same template with different url params that are used to change the data in the template, so IMO it should still re-render.

Comment: hope this helps https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/890#issuecomment-59385312

Comment: @iAmME, interesting. But the reason I want Iron Router to route is to change the data on the page. `data: return Videos.findOne(this.params.id);` in my route never runs because Iron Router refuses to re-render the same template (even though it has a different param now) so the data never updates. What results is that the URL in the browser changes, but the data on the page remains the same.

Comment: what version of iron:router u r using? did you get any error in console? and also make sure subscribing to the data?

Comment: It's the latest version of Iron Router. Meteor 1.01. And yes, subscribing to the data. If I'm currently on `/videos/23456` and I click on a link, the URL changes to `/videos/f4e4w` but no new data gets received because Iron Router never runs. If I'm currently on `/videos/23456` and I manually paste `/videos/f4e4w` into the address bar and press enter the page renders and the data changes. Iron Router either doesn't get invoked on clicking of the link or it sees that the link goes to the same `/videos/blahblahblah` template and doesn't run the `Router.route` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, false alarm. It appears that `Router.route` DOES fire and updates the data context every time the `params._id` changes. I was placing the debugger outside of the Route function when I should have been placing it inside of the data context function.

The example that I gave in this answer was also a highy, highly simplified example. It wasn't working in my real-life project due to something else (a complex video iframe generator) that was being refreshed improperly.

But rest assured that going from `/videos/f4e4w` to `/videos/23456` by clicking a link DOES still go through Iron Router and the params does get read and the data does get updated.

Comment: Can you mark your answer, so it doesn't sit "unanswered"?

Comment: I havr to wait a day or two before stack allows me to mark it.

Comment: ah, my bad, didn't look at the dates... :)